# Computed reverse() mix up in vue 3 ref array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have simple messages array and when new message appear I need to push it to array:

```
const props = defineProps(['conversation'])
const messages = ref(props.conversation.messages) -> [{body: 'Something'}]
const filteredMessages = computed({
    get () {
        return messages.value.slice().reverse();
    }
})

onMounted(() => {
    messages.push({
        body: 'Test 1'
    })
})
```

For some reason, when I use `.reverse()` on array, it displays wrong body value [Something] on screen even tho in dev tools it has the right value [Test 1]. Without `.reverse()` the right value [Test 1] is displayed.

Anyone know why?

Comment: how are you displaying it?  also, based on the code the array should have 2 values in it,(`{body: 'Something'}` from props and `{body: 'Test 1'}` pushed in onMounted), so it's not clear why either of your test results include only one item in the array.

Comment: I thought it was clear that when pushed they would  be displayed as list, anyway it's like its duplicating Something for each push instead of showing pushed ones as in devtools

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what you mean.  Your code doesn't have any issues that I can see whether you have `.reverse()` or not.  See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-browser-nv881i?file=/src/App.vue).  But again I'm not sure how you're displaying the array or how you're only getting a single value displayed on the screen, but if you provide more code it might become clear.